# Knockout JS valueUpdate keypress not working for enable binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a 'Save' button on my form that has knockout enable binding. I added valueUpdate: 'keypress' to my knockout binding expression hoping for save button to become enabled on keypress.  I have a simple input textbox with value knockout binding.  Instead, page still requiring user to click away for save button to become enabled. HTML below. when user types in input, canSave becomes true enabling save button.

```
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave, valueUpdate: 'keypress'">Save</button>

<h3><strong>First Name: <input data-bind="value: firstName"></strong></h3>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `valueUpdate` binding only makes sense coupled with a `value` binding; it should go on your input, not on your button.

```
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave">Save</button>
<h3><strong>First Name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'keypress'"></strong></h3>
```

Also, consider `valueUpdate: 'input'` if you're using browsers new enough to support it, or even the `textInput` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html), if you're using KO >3.2

Comment: This works except the save button doesn't seem to become enabled until there are at least two key presses. For example, if I click in first name and press 1 key, save button still disabled. If I press a second key, then the save button becomes enabled.

Comment: nvm , keypress event seems to require two key presses BUT valueUpdate: 'input' seems to work correctly after just one keypress =) Thanks!

Comment: The reason you were seeing that behavior is that "keypress" updates the observable with the contents of the input when they press the key down... which doesn't include the key that they're about to type.

Comment: please vote up my question if you get a chance and you think its a good question. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: firstName().length > 0">Save</button>

<h3><strong>First Name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate:'keypress'"></strong></h3>
```

from you're code it seems, `firstName` is an observable, if so then above code will do what you need. It will disable the button if there is not input else make it enable.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate:'keyup'"
```

Its working for me.